# creating img_upload_url using django

Tags: python, html, django

I was searching how to upload image to your project using url, most of them were outdated so i would like simply be like i could choose which type upload(from computer or url)
BTW im using python3
current models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)    
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
            null=True, 
            blank=True, 
            width_field="width_field", 
            height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    objects = PostManager()
```

also i have form already

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "image",
            "draft",
            "publish",
        ]
```

and finally views.py

```
def post_create(request):#Kuriamas Post
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)
```

So I just need url based img upload in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of your problem, there are two options here:

#### Just point to the URL in the database (there's no proper up/download)

In that case, you add another optional field in the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

and then add it to the fields in the forms' Meta class

#### --or-- download on the server side when saving the form

You have to add a custom field to the form and then add some logic to process the upload

**forms.py:**

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import urllib2

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    image_url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title", "content", "image", "image_url", "draft", "publish",
        ]

    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(PostForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        image_url = self.cleaned_data.get('image_url',None)
        if image_url and not self.cleaned_data.get('image', None):
            try:
                filename = image_url.split('/')[-1].split('#')[0].split('?')[0]
                imgdata = urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read()
                instance.image.save(filename, ContentFile(imgdata), save=False)
            except:
                pass # Add Exception handling here
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Don't forget to add some exception handling to that basic code because you can't guarantee the URL will load correctly. You can also try to put the download code in the clean method of the form, although it's slightly more complicated than saving the file directly from the model.

Comment: i can't make this code work, first i coulnd't put method save in models because 1) i can't import Postform from forms.py it already has import from models 2) i get error when i put in forms.py 'dict' object is not callable 3) image even wont save

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and have corrected it. Can you let me know if this works?

Comment: seems it works halfway, now it doesn't create any conflitcs, but image don't get saved and also i would be great if it would appear same place as "image" after upload

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify filename and the exception management makes the error silent. Can you retry it now?

Comment: Can you remove the "except" and "try" parts and tell me where you get an error?

Comment: name 'ContentFile' is not defined

Comment: This is an import error. Is ContentFile correctly imported (see the line at the top in my code)